# como hacer un sleep en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Intente con esto pero no funciono:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function demo() {
  console.log('Taking a break...');
  await sleep(2000);
  console.log('Two second later');
}

demo();
```

En mi caso añadi la funcion demo a mi javascript para que antes de que se cierre haga un sleep pero nunca lo hace y se cierra antes, el codigo:

```
/** Represents a timer that can count down. */
function CountdownTimer(seconds, tickRate) {
    this.seconds = seconds || (25*60);
    this.tickRate = tickRate || 500; // Milliseconds
    this.tickFunctions = [];
    this.isRunning = false;
    this.remaining = this.seconds;



    /** CountdownTimer starts ticking down and executes all tick
        functions once per tick. */
    this.start = function() {
        if (this.isRunning) {
            return;
        }

        this.isRunning = true;

        // Set variables related to when this timer started
        var startTime = Date.now(), 
            thisTimer = this;

        // Tick until complete or interrupted
        (function tick() {
            secondsSinceStart = ((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000) | 0;
            var secondsRemaining = thisTimer.remaining - secondsSinceStart;

            // Check if timer has been paused by user
            if (thisTimer.isRunning === false) {
                thisTimer.remaining = secondsRemaining;
            } else {
                if (secondsRemaining > 0) {
                    // Execute another tick in tickRate milliseconds
                    setTimeout(tick, thisTimer.tickRate);
                } else {

                    // Stop this timer
                    thisTimer.remaining = 0;
                    thisTimer.isRunning = false;

                    // Alert user that time is up
                    playAlarm();
                    playAlarm();
                    changeFavicon('green');

                    //run again
                    demo();
                    demo();
                    demo();


                    var elemento = document.getElementById('btn_shortbreak');
                    elemento.click();



                }

                var timeRemaining = parseSeconds(secondsRemaining);

                // Execute each tickFunction in the list with thisTimer
                // as an argument
                thisTimer.tickFunctions.forEach(
                    function(tickFunction) {
                        tickFunction.call(this, 
                                          timeRemaining.minutes, 
                                          timeRemaining.seconds);
                    }, 
                    thisTimer);
            }
        }());        
    };


    this.close = function(){
        window.close();
    };
    /** Pause the timer. */
    this.pause = function() {
        this.isRunning = false;
    };

    /** Pause the timer and reset to its original time. */
    this.reset = function(seconds) {
        this.isRunning = false;
        this.seconds = seconds
        this.remaining = seconds
    };


    /** Add a function to the timer's tickFunctions. */
    this.onTick = function(tickFunction) {
        if (typeof tickFunction === 'function') {
            this.tickFunctions.push(tickFunction);
        }
    };
}

/** Return minutes and seconds from seconds. */
function parseSeconds(seconds) {
    return {
        'minutes': (seconds / 60) | 0,
        'seconds': (seconds % 60) | 0
    }
}

/** Play the selected alarm at selected volume. */
function playAlarm() {
    var alarmValue = document.getElementById('alarm_select').value;
    if (alarmValue != 'none') {
        var alarmAudio = document.getElementById(alarmValue);
        var alarmVolume = document.getElementById('alarm_volume').value;
        alarmAudio.volume = alarmVolume / 100;
        alarmAudio.play();
    }
}


function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function demo() {
  console.log('Taking a break...');
  await sleep(10000);
  console.log('Two second later');
}



/** Change the color of the favicon. */
function changeFavicon(color) {
    document.head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var color = color || 'green';

    var newFavicon = document.createElement('link'),
        oldFavicon = document.getElementById('dynamic-favicon');
    newFavicon.id = 'dynamic-favicon'
    newFavicon.type = 'image/ico';
    newFavicon.rel = 'icon';
    newFavicon.href = 'images/' + color + '_tomato.ico';

    if (oldFavicon) {
        document.head.removeChild(oldFavicon);
    }
    document.head.appendChild(newFavicon);
}

/** Window onload functions. */
window.onload = function () {

     playAlarm();

    var timerDisplay = document.getElementById('timer'),
        customTimeInput = document.getElementById('ipt_custom'),
        timer = new CountdownTimer(),
        timeObj = parseSeconds(25*60);

    /** Set the time on the main clock display and
        set the time remaining section in the title. */
    function setTimeOnAllDisplays(minutes, seconds) {
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            // Add an hours section to all displays
            hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
            minutes = minutes % 60;
            clockHours = hours + ':';
            document.title = '(' + hours + 'h' + minutes + 'm) Pomodoro';
        } else {
            clockHours = '';
            document.title = '(' + minutes + 'm) Pomodoro';
        }

        clockMinutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
        clockMinutes += ':';
        clockSeconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

        timerDisplay.textContent = clockHours + clockMinutes + clockSeconds;
    }

    /** Revert the favicon to red, delete the old timer
        object, and start a new one. */
    function resetMainTimer(seconds) {
        changeFavicon('red');
        timer.pause();
        timer = new CountdownTimer(seconds); 
        timer.onTick(setTimeOnAllDisplays);
    }

    // Set default page timer displays
    setTimeOnAllDisplays(timeObj.minutes, timeObj.seconds);

    timer.onTick(setTimeOnAllDisplays);

    resetMainTimer(5*60);
    timer.start(); 

    var elemento = document.getElementById('btn_shortbreak');
                    elemento.click()

    // Add listeners for start, pause, etc. buttons
    document.getElementById('btn_start').addEventListener(
        'click', function () { 
            timer.start(); 
        });

    document.getElementById('btn_pause').addEventListener(
        'click', function () {
            timer.pause(); 
        });

    document.getElementById('btn_reset').addEventListener(
        'click', function () {
            resetMainTimer(timer.seconds);
            timer.start();
        });

    document.getElementById('btn_pomodoro').addEventListener(
        'click', function () {
            resetMainTimer(25*60);
            timer.start();
        });

    document.getElementById('btn_shortbreak').addEventListener(
        'click', function () {
            resetMainTimer(5*60);
            timer.start();
            window.close();
        });

    document.getElementById('btn_longbreak').addEventListener(
        'click', function () {
            resetMainTimer(15*60);
            timer.start();
        });

    document.getElementById('btn_custom').addEventListener(
        'click', function () {
            customUnits = document.getElementById('custom_units').value
            if (customUnits === 'minutes') {
                resetMainTimer(customTimeInput.value*60);
            } else if (customUnits === 'hours') {
                resetMainTimer(customTimeInput.value*3600);
            } else {
                resetMainTimer(customTimeInput.value);
            }
            timer.start();
        });

    // Bind keyboard shortcut for starting/pausing timer
    Mousetrap.bind('space', function(e) { 
        // Remove default behavior of buttons (page scrolling)
        if (e.preventDefault()) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            e.returnValue = false; //IE
        }

        // Pause or start the timer
        if(timer.isRunning) {
            timer.pause();
        } else {
            timer.start();
        }
    });


    resetMainTimer(5*60);
            timer.start();

};
```

Alguna manera posible de hacer un sleep en javascript para hacer una pausa antes de que cierre mi pagina usando javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Pero no tiene sentido utilizar promesas para hacer un sleep.

Si lo que quieres hacer es ejecutar un código al cabo de x milisegundos sin bloquear la ejecución del resto del código no tienes más que llamar al método `setTimeout`.

Si lo que quieres es que el hilo de ejecución se detenga x milisegundos bloqueando por completo todo el código y continuando después de ese tiempo sí que necesitarías una función "sleep", pero con ejecución síncrona. Algo así:

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
 var start = new Date().getTime();
 for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
  if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
   break;
  }
 }
}

function demo() {
  console.log('Taking a break...');
  sleep(2000);
  console.log('Two second later');
}

demo();
```

Si quieres que tenga un comportamiento asíncrono, como te he dicho antes, no tienes más que hacer un `setTimeout`:

```js
function demo() {
  console.log('Taking a break...');
  setTimeout(console.log.bind(null, 'Two second later'), 2000);
}

demo();
```

La función `sleep` está sacada de: [JavaScript. Función sleep - Píldoras JS](http://pildorasjs.blogspot.com.es/2015/06/javascript-funcion-sleep.html)

Answer (score 0):

En esta parte:

```
//run again
demo();
demo();
demo();

var elemento = document.getElementById('btn_shortbreak');
elemento.click();
```

Estas ejecutando funciones asincronas para luego hacer click al boton que gatilla el cierre. Por lo que claramente la ejecucion continua sin esperar el termino de `demo()`

Si en cambio hubieses ejecutado en el cuerpo de demo:

```
async function demo() {
    console.log('Taking a break...');
    await sleep(2000);
    console.log('Two second later');
    var elemento = document.getElementById('btn_shortbreak');
    elemento.click();
}
```

Hubieras obtenido el comportamiento que buscabas

Comment: esque lo quei ntentaba era que antes de que se cerrase hacer un pitido de la alarma con playAlarm(); pero es sleep nunca me lo hace por tanto no suena la alarma y se cierra al instante. segui la recomendacion pero no pude resolverlo.