# Añadir tiempo o pausa breve a una function en Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una funcion que basicamente lo que hace es que cuando se hace Hover sobre un div es que aparece el Overflow en Y y cuando quito el mouse entonces se retira.

```
$("#todo").hover(
      function() {
        $( this ).css("overflow-y", "scroll");
      }, function() {
         $( this ).css("overflow-y", "hidden");
      }
    );
```

Sin embargo quiero causar un pequeño retardo cuando esto ocurra... En pocas palabras que cuando pase el mouse sobre el div pase 1 o 2 segundos antes de aparecer el scroll, en vez de aparecer inmediatamente.

Comment: Creo que te puede servir [como hacer un sleep en javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142132/como-hacer-un-sleep-en-javascript)

Comment: @the-breaker fue buena idea y la intente, gracias... sin embargo, causa un retraso por ejecución que me perjudica ahora. y segundo, me bloquea luego el hover... Pero fue gran idea gracias.

Comment: lo que quieres es un efecto que puedes hacer con solo css y cambiando la clase

Comment: agrega a tu clase css algo como `transition-delay:1s;`

Comment: Es exactamente lo que deseo lograr, pero haciendolo con CSS solo es imposible debido a que estoy añadiendo el hover con JS, y acabo de intentar añadirlo por JS de igual forma como añadi el otro css pero no me funciona el transition-delay

Comment: puedes pasar parte del codigo html afectado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo es utilizar un ***setTimeout*** y si por cualquier motivo el elemento pierde el ***hover*** antes del tiempo estipulado, entonces se cancelará el ***setTimeout***.

En el ejemplo que dejo se activa, pospone o dispara después de un segundo:

```
var idSetTimeout;

$("#todo").hover(function () {
    idSetTimeout = setTimeout(function (element) {
        if (element.is(":hover")) {
            element.css("overflow-y", "scroll");
        }
    }, 1000, $(this));
}, function () {
    clearTimeout(idSetTimeout);
    $(this).css("overflow-y", "hidden");
});
```

Si te fijas también se realiza una segunda validación donde se verifica si todavía está en hover para actualizar el css.

> [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp): El método setTimeout() llama a una función o evalúa una expresión después de un número específico de milisegundos.
>
> [clearTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp): El método clearTimeout() borra un temporizador configurado con el método setTimeout().

Answer (score 0):

es sencillo

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

en tu caso seria

```
$("#todo").hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).css("overflow-y", "scroll");
  }, function() {
     $( this ).css("overflow-y", "hidden");
  },3000
);
```

3000 = 3 segundos.

Comment: Gracias por comentar sin embargo @Artudoxo, eso no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Usa `setTimeout` pero de esta manera:

```
$("#todo").hover(
    function() {
        //Esta función permite ejecutar una función después
        //de n milisegundos, en tu caso serán 3000, que equivale a 3 segundos
        setTimeout(function(){
            $( this ).css("overflow-y", "scroll");
        }, 3000);
     }, function() {
         //Si también quieres lograr eso cuando el usuario retire el cursor, entonces aquí también necesitarás un setTimeout
         $( this ).css("overflow-y", "hidden");
     });
```

Eso debe servirte.

Sin embargo, dentro de la función que se ejecuta en el `setTimeout`, la referencia a `this` no será la misma que a `$("#todo")`, entonces tienes que usar:

```
$("#todo").css("overflow-y", "scroll");
```

El código quedaría así

```
$("#todo").hover(
    function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#todo").css("overflow-y", "scroll");
        }, 3000);
     }, function() {
         //Si también quieres lograr eso cuando el usuario retire el cursor, entonces aquí también necesitarás un setTimeout
         $( this ).css("overflow-y", "hidden");
     });
```

Recuerda que cada vez que selecciones o manipules el `DOM` usando la función `$` de `jQuery`, estarás ejecutando una gran cantidad de código, una pequeña recomendación sería que guardes en una variable la referencia al objeto que seleccionaste, algo así

```
//Guardamos la referencia a este elemento u objeto, para su reutilización
var todo = $("#todo");

//
todo.hover(
    function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            todo.css("overflow-y", "scroll");
        }, 3000);
     }, function() {
         //Si también quieres lograr eso cuando el usuario retire el cursor, entonces aquí también necesitarás un setTimeout
         todo.css("overflow-y", "hidden");
     });
```

Saludos

Comment: Si retiras el mouse antes de que se cumpla los 3 segundos, entonces se debe cancelar el setTimeout o por lo menos validar que no se aplique el css.

Comment: Si, tienes razón

Answer (score -2):

puedes intentarlo con esto.

```
var a = setInterval(function(){ /*aquí tu código que quieras ejecutar*/ clearInterval(a);}, 3000);
```

asi solo se ejecuta a los 3 segundos y se detiene, ahí la pausa que requiere.

Comment: el usuario quiere una Pausa, no algo que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo

Comment: Como dijo Jack, solo deseo que se ejecute con el hover de la funcion... pero gracias